# How do I load a local file onto Spark using a Jupyter notebook in an EMR cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm struggling to load a local file on an EMR core node into Spark and run a Jupyter notebook. I keep getting errors from the task nodes saying that the file doesn't exist, but I've tried setting the `spark` configuration to be `local`, so I'm not sure how to fix this. The following works when I spin up a 1-node cluster, but fails when I have anything larger than that:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .master("local") \
        .appName("Test") \

df = spark.read.csv('/home/hadoop/dataset.csv')

df.show(n=5)
```

I've tried restarting the Jupyter notebook kernel, but that hasn't fixed anything. So I'd like to know how to either broadcast/share a local file onto the entire cluster, or create a `SparkSession` instance that works. I'm also using the new AWS JupyterHub, if that makes any difference

Comment: Have you tried distributing it to the executors via `spark-submit --files /home/hadoop/dataset.csv ...` option? Also, use a `"file:///home/hadoop/dataset.csv"` when trying to read it to indicate local file system.

Comment: hmm so this works if I use the `spark-submit` command and put the code in a python file. But I still can't get this working on a Jupyter notebook. I'm admittedly stumped as to what I can do.

Comment: You can read a file locally (via pandas?), and then `createDataFrame` https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame from that.

Answer (score 0):

I could't get this to work either, here is my workaround:
(Assuming your problem is in Amazon EMR, too & you have the possibility to use S3 Buckets)

0. (Services -> Storage -> S3 -> Create Bucket -> Bucket name: "emr-data-<account#>" *
1. upload "dataset.csv" into your S3 Bucket "emr-data..."
2. in JupyterNotebook:

   ```
   #store URL: 
   url = "s3n://emr-data-<account#>/dataset.csv"  

   #read json from URL  
   df = spark.read.csv(url, header=True)

   #show first 5 rows of data frame
   df.show(n=5)
   ```

the resulting spark data frame "df" can be used as usual

(* names of S3 Buckets must be unique, thus adding your own account number to the name is one easy way to achieve this. Also, adding the Region to the name (emr-bucket-123456789012-eu-central-1) is good practice)